# Check the null values in android edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here I am trying get values from phone number(editphone) and password(editpassword).So please tell me how to enhance the below code checking null values from the both.

```
 Signbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final ProgressDialog mdialog = new ProgressDialog(signin.this);
            mdialog.setMessage("please waiting...");

            table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).exists())
                    {
                        mdialog.dismiss();
                        user userobj = dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).getValue(user.class);

                        if (userobj.getPassword().equals(editpassword.getText().toString())) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user is not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Try using [TextUtils#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)); which returns a boolean if passed string parameter is `null` or empty string `""`, then if it is false, you can compare the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check null values from the both by following code :

```
Signbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final ProgressDialog mdialog = new ProgressDialog(signin.this);
        mdialog.setMessage("please waiting...");

       if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editphone.getText.toString.trim()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editpassword.getText.toString.trim())) {

        table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).exists())
                {
                    mdialog.dismiss();
                    user userobj = dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).getValue(user.class);

                    if (userobj.getPassword().equals(editpassword.getText().toString())) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                    {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user is not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is the trim() method and what is it used for?

Comment: @Savi trim() method eliminates the leading and trailing spaces. For more go for  this link : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-trim

Answer (score 0):

You can use yourEditText.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") for checking whether your edit text is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Savi, your editText.getText().toString() can never be null, it can be empty string although - "". What you would like to do is just check with .isEmpty().

TextUtils.isEmpty(..) will check your String if it is null or empty, which you do not need in this case, since the null check would be just an overhead.

You can add all other kind of validations, i would suggest you to do them in a validator class or basically to create a common place for validations which can be used by all your views easily and validate them, show hint errors or whatever.

That is about the editText fields, if your getChild method returns null is another story, check what the method returns and only if it is not null continue with your success flow.

Answer (score 0):

Store edittext value in a string and then use TextUtils.isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence) solution provided by @Jay in comment below your question. Then use the boolean value returned by isEmpty(String) to perform null handling.

table_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String str1 = editphone.getText().toString(); // use this at other places too where you are getting string from edittexts
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)){
                 // show your toast or msg or perform any other task
                 return;
                }

                if(dataSnapshot.child(str1).exists())
                {
                    mdialog.dismiss();
                    user userobj = dataSnapshot.child(editphone.getText().toString()).getValue(user.class);

                    if (userobj.getPassword().equals(editpassword.getText().toString())) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                    {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user is not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to define number and password values ​​globally.

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.***);

Null Control:

cb.isChecked();